# Getting NoSuchMethodError at runtime

Tags: java, netbeans, runtime-error, nosuchmethoderror

I have looked through many answers to similar questions. But couldn't narrow down to a solution.

Following is the code: (Simplifying names for readability)

**First class:**

```
package p1;

public class C1 {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("Boom!");    
    }
}
```

**Second class:**

```
package p2;
import p1;

public class C2 {
    public static void main(String[] params) {
        C1.test();    
    }
}
```

Clean-Build doesn't give any error. (No compilation error)

But at runtime I'm getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: C1.test()V
at C2.main(C2.java:6)
  Java Result: 1
```

P.S. I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: `C1.test()V` - That `V` looks suspicious..

Comment: the proper signature for a main method is:  `public static void main(String[] args);`

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's just Java's internal notation for a method that returns `void`.

Comment: Are u using any editor?

Comment: I missed the arguments while posting the question. Sorry. Corrected in the question. Error is not being caused because of that.

Comment: @bludger - so what was the cause of the error then?

Comment: @StephenC I think that was the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you are running your class `C2` with an old version of class `C1` in the classpath (a version that did not yet have the `test()` method).

Make sure you don't have old versions of `C1.class` somewhere. Remove all your `*.class` files and recompile everything, and then try to run it again.

Addition: As Kevin Bowersox noted in a comment, your `main` method must look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

It **must** take a `String[]` as an argument.

Comment: Also the `main` signature is invalid.

Comment: Tried this. Not working. Also clean-build itself deletes all the .class files, right?

Comment: This is really the only reason that you can get such an error. Check again how your project is set up and from where class `C2` references class `C1`. Something is set up in such a way that they are not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

It will properly compile and run only if main function will have String tab as args.
But also check versions of class C1 and C2, try rebuild your project to recompile that classes.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        C1.test();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should import it as 
import p1.*;

Than you will get access to all classes and member functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans sometimes likes to get stuck after some changes and clean build doesn't work then.

Try editing each file that has been recently modified and saving it again (e.g. put a whitespace in a random place). After that, clean and build the project again.

Answer (score -1):

If my memory refreshes and as Jesper pointed out, I also encountered that same issue NoSuchMethodFoundException under that same scenario (having still old class references that have not been cleaned).

I just copied your code snippets with 2 different packages directly in to my netbean, compiled and runned C2. It did print the BOOM! message.

In my case using :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
}
```

does not make a difference when I compiled and runned the code.

```
public static void main(String params[]){
}
```

It makes sense since the main class should have the correct method signature of main.

Here args or params, should not make a huge difference, I believe; as what we have inside the method is simply a reference for the inner body of the method that it uses.

Still definitely it is good practice to follow the standard signature for main.

I would recommend to clean the project and copy the contents from scratch in a new project and build it again, sometimes netbeans can go crazy.